# Filter the content read from file

Tags: filtering, read

(This follows the [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58894/5267) to the  question: [Completion of sentences stored in a file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/58866/5267.]).)

Suppose I have a file, the content of which being organized thanks to `org-mode`:

```
* Dreams ≠ reality 
Please, don't take your dreams for reality: (a + b)² ≠ a² + b².
Please, don't take your dreams for reality: cos(a + b) ≠ cos a + cos b.
No, √(a²) ≠ a.

* Derivatives
You should revise the derivatives.

* General remarks
This only works for a positive x.
```

**Edit after @NickD comments:**

<del>AFAICS, the function used for reading this file, `insert-file-contents`, filters (I mean ignores) empty lines. Is it possible to ask it to filter lines starting with a `*` as well</del>?

Is it possible to ask the function used for reading this file, `insert-file-contents`, or a consequent one, to filter some lines, e.g. those starting with a `*`

Comment: I don't know why you think `insert-file-contents` ignores empty lines, but I don't think that's true.

Comment: @NickD Ah, OK, sorry: should be the way it is used in the linked answer which ignore them (AFAICS).

Comment: That's done by `split-string`: the buffer contents are read as a string, then `split-strig` splits it on newlines and (because of the `t` third argument) it omits null string matches. It has nothing to do with `insert-file-contents`.

Comment: @NickD OK, thanks. I rephrased my question.

Comment: Ar you interested in this in the context of the linked answer? If so, `split-string` takes a TRIM argument that can be used to omit such lines from the result. But that's not going to work in a more general context.

Comment: @NickD Indeed, it is in this context that I would use it. I'll have a look at this TRIM argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to any "Is it possible" question is almost always yes (there is a theorem by Turing which tells us the limit of what is computable, but in practice people rarely come up against that limit). It is better to rephrase this type of question to ask *how* to do something, rather than merely if it is possible, since that's usually what most people mean by it. It's also a good idea to list what you've already tried, and possibly why that didn't work.

You want to use the `seq-remove` function. You can read the documentation for it by typing `C-h f seq-remove <RET>`. You'll see that it takes a predicate function and a sequence, and returns a new sequence comprised of those elements for which the predicate function returns nil.

For the predicate, I recommend writing a lambda that calls `string-match-p`. This returns true when a string matches a regular expression. Again, you can see the documentation for functions with `C-h f`.

Putting those together, something like this ought to work:

```
(seq-remove (lambda (line)
              (string-match-p "^\\*+ " line))
            your-list-of-strings)
```

The elisp manual includes additional documentation about these topics that you might want to read, along with documentation about similar functions that you may soon need. You can open the info browser with `C-h i`. You may have many info manuals installed on your computer, but you should specifically take a look at the Emacs manual and the Elisp manual. Chapters 6.1 Sequences and 34.4 Regular Expression Searching would be good places to start.

Comment: You might want to make the regex just a bit more complicated to match Org mode's headlines: one or more asterisks followed by a space - something like `"^\\*+ "`.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: Eh, the comment was meant more for the OP, since he specifically asked for lines that start with an asterisk, even though he mentioned Org mode. So your answer answered exactly his question: I just thought that his question should have been slightly different :-)

Comment: Yea, but the whole reason I decided to use a regexp here is that I knew the requirements would expand over time; otherwise I would have suggested `(char-equal (aref line 0) ?*)`.

Comment: @db48x I completely agree with your 1st paragraph: it is what always say during the LaTeX courses I'm giving ;) About the documentations, I know them but, despite I'm an Emacs fan, I'm currently unable to understand how `elisp` works: too exotic for me (sorry). Now about your solution, AFAICS, it filters the lines that start with an asterisk by dropping all the other ones but what I'm looking for is exactly the contrary: maybe the right wording I should have used is "How to filter out lines starting with an asterisk"?

Comment: ... or replace the filtering function with one that negates the condition: `(lambda (line)(not (string-match-p "^\\*+ " line)))`

Comment: @db48x: re regexp vs char comparison - absolutely. I agree completely that that is the right choice. I also have no problem with your using either regexp in your answer: I figured that an explanation might help the OP - that's all.

Comment: @NickD Works nicely with the negated condition!

Comment: @db48x  Would you change your answer with the negated condition in order I can accept it?